# Upload user profile picture Firebase - Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I'm using `ImagePicker` to select a profile picture, once picture selected it'll be assigned to a `Circle Avatar` now how can I upload the picture into firebase. If the user refreshes the page(UI) `Circle Avatar` goes back to the default image! I need to replace the `Circle Avatar` with the currentUser's picture.

simply I don't know how to retrieve the image from firebase and assign it into `Circle Avatar`

Here's how I'm trying to update the circle avatar -

```
 CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 30.0,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                            child: (_imageFile != null)
                                ? Container(
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                      image: DecorationImage(
                                          image: FileImage(_imageFile),//Selected Image
                                          fit: BoxFit.fill),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                : Image.network(
                                    (photoUrl == null)
                                        ? 'https://www.materialui.co/materialIcons/image/add_a_photo_black_36x36.png'//Default Picture
                                        : photoUrl,
                                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                  ), //Replace with Image From DB
```

Uploading the picture -

```
Future UpdatePic() async{
   String fileName = basename(_imageFile.path);
  StorageReference firebaseStorageRef =
      FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileName);
  StorageUploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_imageFile);
  StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
  showInSnackBar("Picture updated successfully.");
}
```

This uploads the picture but  I don't know how to retrieve this into `Circle Avatar` of that particular user's profile.

Comment: Why do you want the `photoUrl`? You already have a file reference you can use to show an image.

Comment: Could you please show me an example How can I achieve this? - I'm a newbie to flutter

Comment: I'm looking at *your* code. I can't see an issue with it other than an odd way of showing the file image.

Comment: Just let me know how can I get the file reference from firebase to `Circle Avatar`(reference needs to be the file of currentUser).

Comment: You *already* have the file reference **locally**. It's `_imageFile`. It's the same file you're uploading. There isn't a need to waste resources performing a read from storage if you already have the file.

Comment: Yea, but the `-imageFile` won't appear if the user restarts the application, it'll change back to the default image.

Comment: You should clarify that in your question? What have you tried in retrieving the image from storage? There is lots of documentation.

Comment: Is it possible to retrieve the image of currentUser? I feel like the way I wrote the file into firebase is different cause it has no reference to the user on the database! if it's wrong can you please refer me to a documentation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217746/discussion-between-christopher-moore-and-pranavan).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the download URL of your stored photo:

```
FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref() //if your photos are inside another folder, lets say avatarPhotos
                 // you need to put that here also to get the download URL, with
                 // another .child('avatarPhotos') 
          .child(fileName)
          .getDownloadURL()
          .then((value) => {
                 //here you can either set your photoUrl to value or assuming
                 //assuming you have a database with users with profile pictures, 
                 //you can call a method to update the user with this value
                 photoUrl = value;
              });
    });
```

Then you can take the download URL store it in a variable and output it as you did in your code with Image.network(photoUrl).